# admob google play services - questions on banner ads and screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, google-play-services

At the moment, I have implemented banner ads as described in the developer guide:
I defined my ads in the xml layout files, and initialized them in onCreate() and added entries in onResume(), onPause(), and onDestroy().

Also:
I am using the same ad ID in the layout-port and layout-land versions of the layouts.

2 Questions regarding this setup:

- Should I be doing something to make the ads persist throughout the screen orientation cycle? Or is just recalling

  ```
   // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
  AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
  AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  ```

every time the screen changes orientation OK (in onCreate())?

- Should I have different ad IDs for layout-land and layout-port? Or should both orientations share the same ad ID?

Answer (score 0):

Both orientations can share the same id.  When an ad is running and you rotate your device, the following things are called: onPause, onDestroy, onCreate, onResume in that order.  So, effively, the original ad is destroyed and a new one is created for the new configuration.